# Alternative tactic for `ssreflect`'s `move=>`

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I like using the `move=>` tactic from the `ssreflect` library in cases when the goal is an implication (e.g. A -> B), to make the premise a hypothesis, and make the conclusion the new goal. However, I don't always want to use `ssreflect`.

Is there another Coq tactic that does the same thing without using `ssreflect`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use `intros`: `intros pat` is roughly equivalent to `move=> pat`. Unfortunately, Coq and ssreflect use a different syntax for introduction patterns, so the two are not interchangeable.

Note that nowadays ssreflect is part of the Coq distribution, so you can use the tactic language by simply doing `From Coq Require Import ssreflect.`, without the need for installing a separate library.